# binding inside binding with knockout

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

Im new with knockout and i'm trying to show all enterprise in my database in a list wish is working very well but i also want to show  all contacts for each enterprise still not working.

Entreprise and Contact have a relation -> NumberEnterprise

```
 <tbody id="list" data-bind="foreach: Enterprise">
 <tr class="line">
 <td data-bind="text: NameEnterprise"></td>
 <td data-bind="text: PrioPhone"></td>  
 <td data-bind="with: Enterprise"></td>  
 <td data-bind="Contacts, text:FullName, value : $parent.NumberEnterprise"></td>  
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your databind `data-bind="Contacts,` is invalid as far as I am aware.

To do what you want to do you are on the right track. Here is an example model:

```
function HolderObject(enterPriseArray){
   var self = this;
   self.enterprise = ko.observableArray([]);

   _.each(enterPriseArray, function(e){
          self.enterprise.push(new SomeObject(e));
    });

    ko.applybindings(self) // probably bind it to a div tag somewhere
}

function SomeObject(data){
    var self = this;
    self.nameEnterprise = ko.observable();
    self.prioPhone = ko.observable();
    self.NumberEnterprise = ko.observable();
    self.EnterPrise = ko.observable(new Enterprise(data.fullName)); 
}

function Enterprise(fullName){
   var self = this;
   self.fullName = ko.observable(fullName);
}
```

Then update your table to be something like

```
<tbody id="list" data-bind="foreach: enterprise">
    <tr class="line">
        <td data-bind="text: nameEnterprise "></td>
        <td data-bind="text: prioPhone "></td>  
        <td><span data-bind="text:FullName"></span><span data-bind="value: $parent.NumberEnterprise"></span></td>  
    </tr>
</tbody>
```